# Excel - Averageifs and excluding data range according to dates

Tags: excel

I am trying to average data where I exclude a certain date range (4/1/14 - 8/30/14) and also have additional criteria. I am trying to use averageifs for this. Here is my attempt, dates are in column C:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D12:D8772,$P$12:$P$8772,">100",$C$12:$C$8772,"<4/1/14",$C$12:$C$8772,">8/30/14")
```

It doesn't work since there is a contradiction, I think. I am asking to include everything before 4/1/14 and everything after 8/30/14, which I think Excel looks to as a contradiction.

How can I modify my command to exclude the data range from 4/1/14 - 8/30/14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario the simplest approach, avoiding too much repetition, is probably to use an "array formula" where you can use `+` to simulate `"OR"`, i.e.

`=AVERAGE(IF($P$12:$P$8772>100,IF(($C$12:$C$8772<DATE(2014,4,1))+($C$12:$C$8772>DATE(2014,8,30)),D12:D8772)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Note: you are **including** the last day of August  - 8/31/2014, is that deliberate?

Answer (score 1):

`AVERAGEIFS` uses *all* criteria you offer to select a number. If I understood correctly, you are trying to choose dates before 4/1/14 **OR** after 8/30/14.

To do that you could calculate average by yourself. Do two `SUMIFS`s, as:

```
=SUMIFS(D12:D8772, [... other criteria ...], $C$12:$C$8772, "<4/1/14")
=SUMIFS(D12:D8772, [... other criteria ...], $C$12:$C$8772, ">8/30/14")
```

And sum them both, dividing by the sum of corresponding `COUNTIFS`, such as:

```
=(SUMIFS(D12:D8772, [... other criteria ...], $C$12:$C$8772, "<4/1/14")
  +SUMIFS(D12:D8772, [... other criteria ...], $C$12:$C$8772, ">8/30/14"))
 /
(COUNTIFS(D12:D8772, [... other criteria ...], $C$12:$C$8772, "<4/1/14")
 +COUNTIFS(D12:D8772, [... other criteria ...], $C$12:$C$8772, ">8/30/14"))
```

Hope that helps.